# Hosting an Apache server on a Raspberry Pi with the aim to turn on a light via a simple relay remotely embedded PHP in HTML not functioning

Tags: php, python, apache

I'm hosting a basic website that displays a simple ON/OFF switch in order to turn on an LED strip hooked up to a relay, using `sudo python lighton.py` and `sudo python lightoff.py` respectively. Running this command in the terminal runs fine but when I try to access it locally from a different computer my button presses are unresponsive. My Python works, my HTML works, therefore I can assume something is wrong with my PHP.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['LightON']))
{
    exec("sudo python /home/pi/lighton.py");
}

if (isset($_POST['LightOFF']))
{
    exec("sudo python /home/pi/lightoff.py");
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">

<ul style="list-style:none;">

<li><button class="btn">Light ON</a></li>

<li></li>
<li></li>

<li><button class="btn"> Light OFF</a></li>

</ul>
</form>
</html>
```

I realize that this looks like a simple permissions issue but I have added `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/pi/lighton.py` and `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/pi/lightoff.py` to `visudo` to no avail.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just curious, have you tried running the command as the www-data user from terminal to ensure the permission are working correctly? `sudo -u www-data python  /home/pi/lighton.py`

The other thing you should check is that python is installed for the www-data user and can be run. `sudo -u www-data python` should bring up the standard python terminal

Comment: @XanderLuciano  `sudo -u www-data python /home/pi/lighton.py`  returns `RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!` How would I resolve this?

Comment: @PaulCrovella What if I changed the `<a>` to `<button>`?

Comment: Oh yea, your PHP code is incorrect, you need to to make it `<form action="THISFILE.php" method="post">` and a few other changes to your form to make it post the data. I'll try to write up the proper code later tonight

Comment: @XanderLuciano Would that mean that I would now two forms, one for each file? e.g. `<form action="lighton.py" method="post">` and `form action="lightoff.py" method="post">`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['light']))
    {
        //Light On
        if($_POST['light'])
            exec("sudo python /home/pi/lighton.py");

        //Light Off
        if(!$_POST['light'])
            exec("sudo python /home/pi/lightoff.py");
    }
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <ul style="list-style:none;">
            <li><h3>Light On</h3></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="light" value="true" /></li>
            <li><h3>Light Off</h3></li>
            <li><input type="submit" name="light" value="false" /></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</html>
```

This will submit a variable called light with the value of either true (light on) or false (light off), which will only be executed if the variable light was posted.